# AngularJS Material md-datepicker pantalla en blanco al seleccionar

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Estoy intentando usar un md-datepicker, y en el momento en el que se selecciona, toda la pantalla se queda en blanco excepto el calendario. Me gustaría saber si es posible eliminar este comportamiento. El ejemplo seguido para crear el calendario es [este](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker), y el código actual:

```
<md-input-container flex="50">
          <label>Fecha nacimiento</label>
          <md-datepicker required ng-model="paciente.fecha" md-current-view="year" md-hide-icons="calendar" md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>
          <div ng-messages="paciente.fecha.$error">
            <div ng-message="valid">Use a valid date format</div>
          </div>
</md-input-container>
```

Y al pulsarlo se muestra [image: así].

Gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, era un problema con el CSS de Angular Material. Tenía la versión 1.1.0, actualizando a la versión 1.1.8 ya se soluciona el error.